# Replace string with post_name on sidebar

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'd like to replace all `{POST_NAME}` 's from my text-widgets on `single.php` sidebar. I'm thinking of something like this

```
global $post;
$POST_NAME= $post->post_name;
$sidebar = preg_replace('/\{(POST_NAME)\}/e', "$$1", $sidebar);
```

How can I get sidebar HTML into `\$sidebar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks well and considerations are correct. In order to achieve your goal, I'd collect HTML and wrap it up like this:

Instead of calling `<?php dynamic_sidebar($sidebar_id); ?>` use `<?php dynamic_sidebar_replaced($sidebar_id); ?>` with a function (add it to functions.php) below:

```
function dynamic_sidebar_replaced($sidebar_id) {
    if (is_single()) { // Optionally, to ensure you're at the single post template.

        ob_start(); // Start gathering output
        dynamic_sidebar($sidebar_id);
        global $post;
        $POST_NAME = $post->post_name;
        $sidebar = preg_replace('/\{(POST_NAME)\}/e', "$$1", $sidebar);
        ob_end_clean();

        echo $sidebar;
        return '';
    }
    dynamic_sidebar($sidebar_id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a particularly good way to do this universally. You can use the [`widget_display_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/) filter to modify a widget instance before it is output, but this can be overridden by widgets. You could go through all the widgets and replace their callbacks with a wrapper of your own. But editing the instance won't guarantee you have access to the output as expected.

The only way I can think to guarantee it is to buffer and capture the output of `dynamic_sidebar` do your string replacement and print out the modified string.

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' );
$sidebar_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo str_replace( '{POST_NAME}', $post->post_name, $sidebar_string );
```